# How do you properly load files within a script with luabind?

Tags: c++, lua, luabind

I am trying to embed Lua into a game. What I want to do is to create a load function, which will load all files in a folder and then create objects based off those files which will be stored on the C++ side. However, if I use something like dofile, it pollutes everything with the variables that are in that file. How do I change this import to be local?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use `loadfile` to get the function based on the file content, then `setfenv(fn,{})` to set the environment, and then call that function (probably wrapped into `pcall`):

```
local fn, err = loadfile("myfile")
if fn then
  setfenv(fn,{})
  local ok, err = pcall(fn)
  if not ok then error(err) end
else
  error(err)
end
```

You can also populate the table you pass to `setfenv` with the values you need the script to have access to or provide access to the global environment with something like:

```
local env = {}
setmetatable(env,{__index = _G})
setfenv(fn,env)
```

This is all for Lua 5.1.

Comment: This is nice Lua code, but I'm guessing that he wants the C++ equivalent.